# How to check loop.php is called from which file or code?

Tags: wordpress

I want to check in loop.php file from which code it is called

Like i call it as `<?php get_template_part('loop','index'); ?>`
and secondly i call it as `<?php get_template_part('loop', 'category'); ?>`

i want to give different `<div>` structure & style according to differentiation.

like if loop.php is called from category.php page then font-color of title should be red otherwise blue.

Any IDEA...?

Comment: you may also try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you also might find people are more willing to answer questions if you accept some of the answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to make this yourself by modifying code, then I think you are looking for the 
`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` variable in order to be able to figure out if `loop.php` is called from `category.php` or `index.php`

Comment: i can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] & then checking for cat exist in url or not ? Any other way you know ?

Comment: If it is in the url then that is a solution as well